# Store Templated data type in a struct

Tags: c++, templates

We are using a PubSub framework that uses template methods to register topics and identify as a publisher or subscriber. For example, to register a topic name in the system you'd call:

```
RegisterTopic<T>(std::string topicName);
```

I would like to be able to create a parameter list (or configuration list if you will) to identify the needed registration topics in use by a given application configuration using a simple struct like

```
struct RegistrationTopicType
{
    std::string name;
    int type;  // replace with some mechanism to store a data type
};
```

However I haven't found a working mechanism to replace the int in the struct above with something to store a data type.

I'm trying to do this so that I can maintain a list of topics and their types in the system:

```
std::vector<RegistrationTopicType> topicList = {
    {"topic1", MyClass},
    {"topic2", MyOtherClass}, // and on and on.
};
```

which I could use later do things like call the templated Registration method.

```
for (auto & topic : topicList) {
  RegisterTopic<topic.type>(topic.name);
}
```

I have experimented with templated struct where I tried to store the data type such as

```
template<typename T>
struct TemplatedRegistrationTopic
{
    using DataType       = T;
    std::string name;
};
```

But while I can implement instances of this struct,

```
TemplatedRegistrationTopic <float> topic{"floatTopic"};
TemplatedRegistrationTopic <MyClass> topic{"MyClassTopic"};
```

I can't seem to access the "DataType" variable as a datatype to use in the Registration method.

```
RegisterTopic<topic.DataType>(topic.name); // this fails.
```

I saw somewhere to use '::' but that also fails:

```
Register<topic::DataType>(topic.name); // this also fails.
```

Problems of storing a bunch of topics of different types in a common list aside, is what I'm trying to do (store a data type for later use in a templated method) even possible?

In the ol' days I might have created an enum list with an enum for of the possible types and then used that to select the actual type in a massive switch statement, but I don't want to have to maintain a mapping between all of the possible types and an enum in a giant switch statement which seems to defeat the purpose of using templates. eg I don't want to end up with this, but its effectively what I'm trying to do:

```
enum typelist { Type1, Type2 }; // one for each type that might be used as a topic

struct EnumRegistrationTopicType
{
    std::string name;
    typelist type;
};

std::vector<EnumRegistrationTopicType> enumTopicList = {
    {"topic1", Type1},
    {"topic2", Type2}, // and on and on.
};

for (auto & topic : enumTopicList) {
  switch (topic.type) {
  case typelist::Type1:
    RegisterTopic<MyClass1>(topic.name);
    break;
  case typelist::Type2:        
    RegisterTopic<MyClass2>(topic.name);
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to be able to add topics to topic list during runtime (the startup phase of the application), but if its not possible I'd be interested to know how I could create such a list as a static array. Then at least Publishers or subscribers could get the topic out of the list (or array or map..) to do things with. This would constrain them, but also ensure that code wasn't trying to do things with topics that didn't exist.

Comment: You might take a look at `std::variant`

Comment: `DataType` is not a variable. It is a member type. You can access it as `decltype(topic)::type` but do you really want it? "its effectively what I'm trying to do" so why not do just that?

Answer (score 2):

Let's do a classic OO design.

```
 struct RegistratorBase {
   virtual ~RegistratorBase() = default;
   virtual void doRegistration(const std::string& topic) const = 0;
 };

 template <typename T>
 struct Registrator {
    void registerTopic(const std::string& topic) const override {
        doRegistration<MyClass1>(topic);
    }
 };

 struct RegistrationTopicType {
     std::string name;
     std::unique_ptr<RegistratorBase> registrator;
 }
```

Now you can add these things to a vector

```
 std::vector<RegistrationTopicType> topicList {
     { "topic1", new Registrator<MyClass1> },
     { "topic2", new Registrator<MyClass2> },
 };
```

and register everything

```
 for (const auto& topic: topicList) {
    topic.registrator->doRegistration(topic.name);
 }
```

Of course now one starts to wonder, why is RegistrationTopicType needed at all? Why not shove the name directly to the Registrator? OK let's try:

```
 struct RegistratorBase {
   virtual ~RegistratorBase() = default;
   // no need for other virtual members
 };

 template <typename T>
 struct Registrator {
    Registrator (const string& topic) {
       RegisteerTopic<T>(topic);
    }
 };
```

Nice! Now let's put this into a vector:

```
 std::vector<std::unique_ptr<RegistratorBase>> topicList {
    new Registrator<MyClass1>("topic1"),
    new Registrator<MyClass2>("topic2")
 };
```

Great! But why do we need a vector of these things? We construct the vector of registrators and never use it anymore. Why not just create a bunch of variables instead?

```
 Registrator<MyClass1> r1("topic1");
 Registrator<MyClass2> r2("topic2");
```

But that's not really different from a list of function calls:

```
 RegisterTopic<MyClass1>("topic1");     
 RegisterTopic<MyClass2>("topic2");
```

So variables are not needed either, nor are their classes. Put the calls somewhere and you are done. *They* are your configuration list.

We have successfully designed, simplified, and finally eliminated a totally redundant software component!

Perhaps some of the simplification steps will not be applicable to your case, in which case the component will not be redundant for you. But I have no way of knowing that.

Comment: Awesome input. Let me apply this to my use case to see if I can make it work. Thanks!

Comment: One note, that I shall add to my original post is that I will need to reuse this list after the initial registration for other tasks.